# Is there a filter for get_post_custom()?

Tags: plugins, filters, post-meta

I know there's a filter get_post_content that I can hook into, but that only seems to work with get_post_meta, I need to filter individual values of get_post_custom() by checking if the metadata key matches like:

```
function filter_custom($meta)
{
    foreach($meta as $k => $v)
    {

        if ($k === 'some_key') return $v . 'filtered';

    }
}
add_filter('get_post_custom', 'filter_custom');
```

Is there a hook for this? if not what would be the best way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way to answer this question is to follow the code. See [`get_post_custom`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) in Codex. Scroll down to **Source Code** section:

> get_post_custom() is located in [wp-includes/post.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/post.php#L1822)

There we'll see that `get_post_custom` calls [`get_post_meta`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/post.php#L1769), which then calls [`get_metadata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_metadata), which points us to:

> get_metadata() is located in [wp-includes/meta.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L269)

there we'll finally see the available filter:

```
$check = apply_filters( "get_{$meta_type}_metadata", null, $object_id, $meta_key, $single );
```

in this case, `post` is the `$meta_type`, so our filter is `get_post_metadata`